# How to get color text using the IMPORTXML?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am monitoring prices on the website, and for this particular one, they communicate promotions changing the price color to red (#ed1c24).

How can I find the XPath that returns me to the color of the text?

product example - https://www.rimi.ee/epood/en/products/alcohol/cocktails-mixed-drinks/muu-alk-jook-g-n-red-orange-5-5-vol-1-5l/p/1363682

How can I get the color of the field using the IMPORTXML?